# How does "water therapy" work to treat muscle tension?

Tags: water, muscle

I read on http://www.spine-health.com/glossary/muscle-tension:

> Muscle tension refers to the condition in which muscles of the body remain semi-contracted for an extended period. Muscle tension is typically caused by the physiological effects of stress and can lead to episodes of back pain.
>
> Stress may change the body's nervous system by constricting blood
>   vessels and reducing blood flow to the soft tissues, including
>   muscles, tendons, and nerves in the back. This process causes a
>   decrease in oxygen and a buildup of biochemical waste products in the
>   muscles, resulting in muscle tension, spasm, and back pain.
>
> **Muscle tension is typically treated using** nonsurgical options to relax
>   the muscles including exercise, **water therapy**, and heat therapy.

How does "water therapy" work to treat muscle tension (e.g., how much water intake, how often, etc.), and has any scientific study confirm that "water therapy" help treat muscle tension?

I am mostly interested in forearm muscles. My goal in preventing muscles tightness is to avoid perturbing the tendons that attach to the epicondyles at the elbow end of the humerus.